# divs not deleting using javascript

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't this code work? it is results.js in the html

```
function clear() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    elem.remove();
}
if (search = "cats") {
    clear();
}
```

It is supposed to delete all the div's if people search clear.
The html is this -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="MHLyrfy29CvaiZP0UXiqotKPpzi75UWP3cc4UyCLFLE" />
        <meta name="Description" content="The new, different search engine of the future. Made nonprofit, Made open. ">
        <title>Alium</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="googel.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="googel.png">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="search">
        <!--Alium Logo-->
        <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
        <img src="googel.png" width="100" height="100">
        <h1 style="margin: inherit;">
                <red>A</red><orange>l</orange><yellow>i</yellow><green>u</green><blue>m</blue>
        </h1>
        <h2><red>Different</red> <orange>and</orange> <yellow>new</yellow> <green>and</green> <blue>good.</blue></h2>
        </div>
        <!--Search-->
<form style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" autocomplete="false" name="search" id="search" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <label>Search Alium...</label>
      </div>
</form>
</div>
        <!--Results-->
        <script src="results.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <!--End-->
        <!--This site is real and made by real people-->
        <!--
        /////////////////////////////////////
        ///////Don't//////////Worry//////////
        ////////////////:)///////////////////
        ////////Be////////////Happy//////////
        /////////////////////////////////////
        /////////////////////////////////////
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Do you know what the problem is?
I need help with this since I am a beginner in html and js and i am teaching myself.

Comment: You'll need to show the code where search is set and demonstrate how this is called for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Note the s in `getElementsByTagName`. That function returns a collection of items. When you have a collection of something you usually need to go through it and pull each item out and operate on it.

Comment: `=` is assignment, not an equality test.

Comment: If you had opened your console you would have seen an error. This question shows little to no effort, as such this should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

To delete elements in javascript you need to get the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) and call [`removeChild(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) on the elements you want deleted.

Your clear function would then look like this:

```
function clear() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    [].forEach.call(elem, function(element){
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    });
}
```

Your comparison should also be `search == "cats"`, as of now you're assigning `cats` to your `search` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "search" is, but I made it as just a window prompt. Here is a fiddle you can test with: https://jsfiddle.net/gg787hto/1/

General idea:

```
function clear() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elem);
    elements.forEach((element) => element.parentNode.removeChild(element));
}

var search = window.prompt("Enter your search");


if (search == "cats") {
    clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 5 sample divs in the html(or even your html):
Instead of getElementsByTagName("div"), use querySelectorAll("div").
On chrome, getElementsByTagName("div") solution doesn't even work.
It's generally not a good idea to iterate a live collection which is returned by 
getElementsByTagName(), from performance point of view as well. Also, since deletion occurs from a live collection, the collection keeps changing causing wrong results. Hence querySelectorAll() comes to rescue and gives right results.

Also, you may want to correct the code that says `if (search = "cats") {` since that looks like attempt to `==` but you wrote `=`.

```
function clear() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
if (search = "cats") {
clear();
 }
```

//HTML markup below:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: @Richard Lobo Did you try my solution?